# Installing Issue in the Debian-Linux Server

Tags: linux, debian, kyotocabinet

I am trying to install [Kyoto Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/) in the Debian-Linux Server by using [this](http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/spex.html) commands. However, when I execute

> ./configure

Command, it gives error

> -bash: ./configure: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Can anybody help me why is this happening and how to solve this issue ? Or any idea why this error can happen ?

Comment: Dos versus Unix/Linux line endings, probably. But this is really off Topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @talonmies, how to solve that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the ^M character, the configure file is probably using Windows-style line endings.

Try to convert it to use UNIX-style:

```
dos2unix configure
```

or in vi type:

```
:set fileformat=unix
```

than save the script and try again.

Answer (score 0):

kyotocabinet is now packaged in debian sid

apt-get install libkyotocabinet-dev --install-suggests

you may need to add this to /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://cdn.debian.net/debian sid main

Answer (score 0):

For me, an initial installation of Kyoto Cabinet (K.C.) was unsuccessful because C++ and zlib were missing from minimal Centos 6. Eventually, these omissions were discovered and K.C. installed (initial instructions from http://skipperkongen.dk/2013/02/14/giving-kyotocabinet-a-go/):

yum -y install gcc-c++ 
yum -y install zlib-devel

wget http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/pkg/kyotocabinet-1.2.76.tar.gz
tar xzvf kyotocabinet-1.2.76.tar.gz
cd kyotocabinet-1.2.76
./configure && make && make install # takes some time!

Test Kyoto Cabinet with: 
kcprototest wicked 5

Answer (score 0):

To install the Kyoto Cabinet API for Python (initial instructions from others):

Test Kyoto Cabinet with: 
kcprototest wicked 5

As root, of course:
cd $HOME

yum -y install python-devel

wget http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/pythonlegacypkg/kyotocabinet-python-legacy-1.18.tar.gz

tar xzvf kyotocabinet-python-legacy-1.18.tar.gz

cd kyotocabinet-python-legacy-1.18

python setup.py install # may take some time!

Create and run a test program, e.g., testkc.py, from the Kyoto Cabint web site.
It should run OK.

You probably want to make K.C. available outside root. Create a new file:
vi /etc/ld.so.conf.d/usrlocal.conf

and add the line:
/usr/local/lib

Then run
ldconfig -v

Move the testkc.py to a user account and run it there; it should be OK